# How to use Tradingview strategys

Tags: pine-script

If I want to run a random strategy like this from TV on lets say Alertatron, what should I write here?

I just want the strategy to do the buying and selling in BTC with current config.

```
"My Strategy (22, 3, 5, 20, 10, 5): order {{strategy.order.action}} @ {{strategy.order.contracts}} filled on {{ticker}}. New strategy position is {{strategy.position_size}}"
```

I assume I write "myAPIkeys in the beginning of the strategy but what else?

Like; myAPIkeyes My Strategy (22, 3, 5, 20, 10, 5): order and so on?

Comment: It is not a super beginner question, it is complicated actually. I just wrote one stratey yesterday that sends messages to Alertatron for someone else. After you are done with your Tradingview strategey, you need to write some piece of code for Alertatron too. This way they can communicate with each other. Read [this](https://alertatron.com/docs/automated-trading/basic-concepts) great documentation. You can find examples and explanations for pretty much every command you need.

Comment: However, I would advise you to get support from a professional for this or test this on paper trading first.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have read the tutorials for Alertatron and figured out how to do simple buy/sell commands from alerts in TV which works, but since I want the strategy to do all the buying/selling I figured there must be some sort of template which include only myAPIkeys and then the strategy takes care of the rest?